# Odin: How to cut notification sound of applications installed using flathub / deb?

Tags: notifications, odin

I cannot cut the notification sounds for applications like Slack or Spotify installed using sideload / flathub or a deb file.

I removed the sounds of all entries in the notification menu but I still have the sounds... The only solution is to enable "Do not disturb" mode...

Is there a way to have these apps in the notification menu ?

Thanks,

Damien

Comment: Is it *just* the notification sound that you’d like to stop, or all sounds from the application(s), including calls?

Comment: Hi,
Just the notification sound of a message in slack

Comment: Can anybody can help ?